# Does the order of data augmentation and normalization matter?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, keras, image-processing, data-science

What is the preferred order of data augmentation and normalization? Is it the former followed by the latter?

Comment: Although I'm not really an expert in this topic, I would say that normalization should be applied **after** data augmentation, given that the latter can change e.g. the range of values of the inputs, and neural networks should generally learn better when the inputs are normalized.